# TOMCAT 6 Problems with DataSourceFactory and SQLServerDriver

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, database-connection, tomcat6

I'm working with TOMCAT6.

In the context.xml I changed the connection pool to tomcat jdbc connection pool. I dropped the dependent jars in the lib, added the factory to the context and all seems to work just fine until TOMCAT tries to lookup MS SQLServerDriver.

> org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup 
>   WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference java.sql.SQLException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

I do not have this problem when I use the default Commons DBCP implementation (simply by removing the factory attribute).

Here is the resource definition within the Context.xml configuration

```
<Resource
    RTentry="True" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" 
    username="xxxx"
    password="xxxx" 
    driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://MSSQL02\LIFETIME:49658;databaseName=MSSQL02_LT23" 
    maxActive="8" 
    maxIdle="4" 
    name="jdbc/LifetimeDB" />
```

Does anyone has a clue how this can happen?

Comment: The problem is caused by class not found exception. It seems that Commons DBCP accepts that the driver is loaded at a later moment by the web application (the jar is located in the web application). If I put the jar in the lib I don't get this exception anymore, but sadly enough the connection fails.

Comment: Had the same problem on Tomcat 7 when switching from DBCP to Tomcat JDBC connection pool and resolved it like you did. However, I don't experience connection failure, everything works perfectly.